# Homology groups and inclusions

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness, homology-cohomology

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact. Suppose that $\mathbb{R}^k \setminus (X \cap\mathbb{R}^k)$ is not connected for some $k < n$. Does it imply that $X$ has nontrivial homology groups?

edited: add an assumption that  $k > 1$ (otherwise it is false as mantioned below)

Comment: How do you embed $\mathbb R^k$ in $\mathbb R^n$ ? Via $\mathbb R^k\times \{0\}^{n-k}\subset \mathbb R^n$? 

Anyway, in this case, you can take $X=[-1,1]^2\subset \mathbb R^2$ for example. It is a contractible space but $\mathbb R\backslash (X\cap \mathbb R)=(-\infty,-1)\cup (1,+\infty)$ is not connected.

Comment: You are right, point disconnects $\mathbb{R}$. What about the conjecture if we add an assumption that k > 1 ?

Comment: Please clarify how you embed $R^k$ into $R^n$. Do you mean there is such a hyperplane, or that for all hyperplanes intersecting $X$ the assumtion holds?

Comment: I mean there is such a hyperplane. I think that the way of embedding as a hyperspace doesn't really matter, but if you want you can take the canonical one (see Bebop above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can again find a counter example of your conjecture :

Let $X=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\leq 0\}\subset \mathbb R^3$ be the south hemisphere. This is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^3$ homeomorphic to a closed disk thus having trivial homology groups.

But for any $k\in (-1,0]$, the intersection of the hyperplane $H_k=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: z=k\}\subset \mathbb R^3$ and $X$ is a circle. So $H_k\backslash (H_k\cap X)$ looks like a plane minus a circle which is not connected.